# Finding the Length of a String within an ArrayList

Tags: java

I am writing a CSVParser program that seperates words at commas. I am currently trying to find and record the longest word that appears in the file. Here is my class.

```
import csv.CSVParser;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class RecordFormatter {

public static void main (String[] args) {
       CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(new File (args[0]));
       while (parser.hasNextLine()) {
              ArrayList<String> ls = parser.getNextLine();
              for (int i = 0; i<ls.size(); i++) {
                   System.out.print("|" + ls.get(i) + " ");
                   }
              System.out.print("|");
              System.out.println();
       }
      CSVParser parser1 = new CSVParser(new File (args[0]));
      ArrayList<Integer> maxCol = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      while (parser1.hasNextLine()) {
            ArrayList<String> ls1 = parser1.getNextLine();
            for (int i = 0; i<ls1.size(); i++) {
                 maxCol.add(ls1.get(i)); //Here is where my bug occurs.
            }
      }

}

}
```

I have created two CSVParsers and am trying to use the second of the two to record the length. I tried (as you can see above) storing the int length value of each word into another Arraylist, but I can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain "I can't seem to get it to work"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without giving the solution, since this is homework...

Notice that you are keeping every length value rather than comparing the current length against a previous value to determine if it is longer and only then keeping it.

Seems like you need just a single maxLength Integer (or int) rather than a list since you just want the longest single word.

If you wanted the longest word per line, a List might then be appropriate.

Another option would be to use a SortedList and get the largest value (last value) in the list.

Comment: I tried that as well. The main thing I'm concerned with is once I have the words stored in the array list, how do I go about finding the length of the word in the Array List? A .get() call returns an object, not a string, in which I wasn't able to check its length.

Comment: Don't store the Strings in a list, retrieve the String's length and either add it to a SortedList or store it in a single value that you compare against.

Comment: ls.get(i) gives you a String instance, since ArrayList is parameterized. Otherwise, go with the advice of John B. Probably the problem lies within CSVParser?

Comment: As per the assignment, they must be stored in an ArrayList.

Comment: You have them in an ArrayList from the CSVParser. All your code is doing is copying them to another ArrayList. If that is REALLY required fine, but as you are copying, calculate the length of each and store the length (and possibly value) of the longest String.